# Apply JS function to multiple elements individually

Tags: javascript, this

I'm not fully understanding 'this', I have checked [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218854/applying-js-function-and-event-listener-to-multiple-html-elements) to the same question, but as the base code was quite different I found I was getting lost. I couldn't figure out what I should be binding meanwhile some of the other answers didn't use 'this' or binding at all.

I am trying to do something very simple, add and remove a class from a single element when clicked, but I want to apply this to multiple elements with only the one clicked triggering each time.

I would like to understand and do this in JS, not jQuery. Which would be an easy short cut but leave me just as baffled.

```js
const flipCard = document.querySelectorAll(".card--holder");
const card = document.getElementById("card");

flipCard.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener("click", flipCards);
})

const flipCards = () => {
  if (card.classList.contains("flipped")) {
    this.classList.remove("flipped");
  } else {
    this.classList.add("flipped");
  }
}
```

```css
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: blue;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="card--holder flip">
    <div class="card" id="card">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="card--holder flip">
    <div class="card" id="card">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card--holder flip">
    <div class="card" id="card">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should use unique identifiers for id attribute or get cards by query selector as well with class.

Comment: @MaxSinev thats not the answer for what he asked, there is definitely a solution.

Comment: The problem is that `flipCards` is an arrow function, which closes over the `this` where it's defined rather than having it set by how it's called. See the linked question's answers for details. The solutions are either 1. Don't use an arrow function so that `this` is controlled by how the function is called (and thus will refer to the element the event was hooked on), or 2. Keep using an arrow and accept the event object you receive as a parameter, and use its `currentTarget` property. That will be what `this` would be with a traditional function.

Comment: Note: `id`s **must** be unique in a document, you can't have the same `id` on more than one element. (But it's a side issue to what you're asking.)

Comment: Also in this case you can't use `flipCards` before it's defined because it's defined using `const`. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6).

Answer (score 0):

Some points:

- You need to define the `flipCards` constant before you use it.
- `ids` have to be unique in HTML
- `this` is incorrect in arrow functions, you need to use the first function parameter and `target` property to get the click target element. And as you want to have the parent selected, you need to get this with `closest`, because the `click` target is inside of the element, in your example.

```js
const flipCards = event => {
  var parent = event.target.closest(".card--holder");

  if (parent.classList.contains("flipped")) {
    parent.classList.remove("flipped");
  } else {
    parent.classList.add("flipped");
  }
}

const flipCard = document.querySelectorAll(".card--holder");
const card = document.getElementById("card");

flipCard.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener("click", flipCards);
})
```

```css
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: blue;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flipped .card .front {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="card--holder flip">
    <div class="card" id="card1">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card--holder flip">
    <div class="card" id="card2">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card--holder flip">
    <div class="card" id="card3">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>
```